# View strongly-typed with ViewModel doesn't generate fields automatically

Tags: asp.net-mvc, viewmodel

When I create a view and bind it directly to one class which has the properties I want to show on the view, the fields (textboxes, etc.) for it are created automatically. But when I create a ViewModel to encapsulate more than one object with data, this doesn't happen. Is there any way to get that working for a specific object which is inside the ViewModel?

Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean when you create a ViewModel with more than one object? I am not aware of any mechanism to automatically create ViewModels from Views or Models in Visual Studio 2008 or 2010 with ASP.NET MVC. Please elaborate

Comment: No, it's actually create a view from a ViewModel. For example, if my model is a Person with properties Name and Age, the view will be generated with two textboxes. But, if instead I have a ViewModel which encapsulates the Person object and other objects I will use, the View creation mechanism doesn't create the textboxes for Name and Age, because Person is inside that ViewModel. How indicate that I want the view to create textboxes for the Person, inside my ViewModel wrapper?

Comment: Are you expecting Visual Studio wizards write the code in your place? They do at some extent but you will have to get the initiative at some moment.

Comment: Okay, I get it, you want VS to go *deeper* inside your ViewModels, we could say you want somekind of *recursion* through your classes and build a View for you. I think this won't work, it does not have that kind of feature. You can however use it to create a View for each of the classes individually then copy that HTML to one unified View but you will have to do that manually. Also I do not know if model binding will still work after that.

Comment: @mare, model binding still works.  I bind to graphs all the time.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the commenters for teasing out the answer details.

MVC's default EditorFor "master" template, Object.ascx, has an if statement in place to prevent this from happening.

To change this behavior you need to replace the base /EditorTemplates/Object.ascx template with your own.  This is a good replica of the template baked into MVC:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl" %>
<% if (Model == null) { %>
    <%= ViewData.ModelMetadata.NullDisplayText %>
<% } else if (ViewData.TemplateInfo.TemplateDepth > 1) { %>
    <%= ViewData.ModelMetadata.SimpleDisplayText %>
<% } else { %>
    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
    <% foreach (var prop in ViewData.ModelMetadata.Properties.Where(pm => pm.ShowForDisplay && !ViewData.TemplateInfo.Visited(pm))) { %>
        <% if (prop.HideSurroundingHtml) { %>
            <%= Html.Display(prop.PropertyName) %>
        <% } else { %>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <div class="display-label" style="text-align: right;">
                        <%= prop.GetDisplayName() %>
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <div class="display-field">
                        <%= Html.Display(prop.PropertyName) %>
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>  
        <% } %>
    <% }   %>
    </table>
<% } %>
```

This line:

```
<% } else if (ViewData.TemplateInfo.TemplateDepth > 1) { %>
```

tell the template to only go down a single level of your object graph.  Simply replace the 1 with 2 or remove it entirely to change how far MVC will drill down.

More details about this template can be found here:
http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2009/10/aspnet-mvc-2-templates-part-4-custom-object-templates.html

( man, I should create a macro to linking to Brad Wilson's stuff, I do it all the time ) ;)